# AWS and ELB Network throughput limits

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elasticsearch

My site runs on AWS and uses ELB

I regularly see 2K con-current users, and during these times, requests through my stack would become slow and take a long time to get a response (30s-50s)

None of my servers or database at this time, would show significant load.

Which leads me to believe my issue could be related to ELB. 
I have added some images of a busy day on my site, which shows graphs of my main ELB. Can you perhaps spot something that would give me insight into my problem?

Thanks!
[image: ELB Image 1]
[image: ELB Image 2]

**UPDATE**

The ELB in the screengrabs is my main ELB forwarding to multiple varnish cache servers. In my varnish vcl I would send misses for a couple of URL's but varnish have a queing behavior and what I ended up doing was set a high ttl for these request, and return hit_for_pass for them. What this does is let varnish know in the vcl_recv that these requests should be passed to the back-end immediately. Since doing this, the problem outlined above has completely been fixed

Comment: A critical piece of missing info is what your logs look like.  You will need to review the logs on your instances, particularly how long the requests are taking as far as the instances, themselves, are concerned... and compare this with the ELB logs for the same requests.  Without that information, you're guessing.

Comment: *"Logs won't tell me anything."*  In that case, fix your logs so that they tell you the processing time for each request, like the ELB logs do.  A discrepancy between the time ELB reports and what your app reports on a given request will help pinpoint the problem.  Not considering the logs as a source of valuable insight means you're mostly just guessing.  Whether your instances are (apparently) under "load" or not isn't necessarily meaningful by itself, and the blog post appears to be about load balancing TCP, not HTTP, which would be an entirely different behavior model in ELB.

Answer (score 0):

did you ssh into one of the servers? Maybe you reach some connection limit in apache or whatever server you run. Also check the cloudwatch monitors of EBS volumes attached to your instances, maybe they cause a io bottleneck.